# How are these methods in my view controller instance methods?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am new to iOS programming. I see that there are functions defined in my view controller such as

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
```

How is `viewDidLoad` an instance method as denoted by the hyphen? I don't think I ever instantiate this class.

Comment: The view controller must be instantiated somewhere if you're using it. Perhaps it's in your xib? Is it the window's root view controller (probably created by your application delegate)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a *.xib file (the view) in Xcode and set its class (the controller) in the identity inspector, an instance of that class is instantiated when you load the *.xib file via

```
[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil]
```

And `viewDidLoad` is called automatically once the *.xib file has fully loaded.

You can see this by simply creating a new Single View iOS project in Xcode. In AppDelegate.m you'll see a line similar to the one above in the `-(BOOL) application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method. In the ViewController.xib file, if you click on "File's Owner" and show the Identity Inspector, you'll see that the class `ViewController` is the one "linked" with the *.xib.

Answer (score 1):

viewDidLoad is a method of the class UIViewController, it is called when the viewcontrollers view loads...[here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is a reference to documentation on the class

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C differentiates between *instance methods* and *class methods*.

An **instance method** is a message that can be sent to an instance of a class (i.e. an object variable), and a **class method** is a message that can only be sent to the class itself:

```
@interface MyClass { }
+ (void)someClassMethod();
- (void)someInstanceMethod()
@end
```

These methods would be called as follows:

```
[MyClass someClassMethod];

id myObject = [[myClass alloc] init];
[myObject someInstanceMethod];
```

Answer (score 1):

`- (void)viewDidLoad` is declared in UIViewController, so any subclass of a UIViewController you create will call this method automatically when it's view loads.  Apple just provides it to users in the default template as the place for developers to do any kind of last minute initialization on the view.  So you might think you didn't instantiate this class, but you did when you made a UIViewController.

If you look in the header file for UIViewController you'll find this...

> - (void)viewDidLoad; // Called after the view has been loaded. For view controllers created in code, this is after -loadView. For view
>     controllers unarchived from a nib, this is after the view is set.

Answer (score 1):

The (void)viewDidLoad is called when the view is loaded ,(when the view appears) , so never call any calss's viewDidLoad exclusively otherwise you have to maintain the stacks as MVC has its stack for calling these methods . viewDidLoad will be called when first time view appears and it wont be called if view goes to background and comes to foreground .